# How to change the border color of a ListView in WinAPI?

Tags: .net, c, winapi

I have noticed that the border color for a ListView in WinAPI is different from .NET:

[image]

Why is it different in .NET? I assume that the .NET code that creates the ListView simply calls `CreateWindowEx()`, so does .NET also calls another code that changes the border color?

Comment: We can't be 100% sure how to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using this:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, 0, WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD...)
```

Don't set `WS_BORDER` flag. Instead use `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` for `dwExStyle`:

```
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, 0, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD...)
```